# MySQL: mass insert new records or increment existing

Tags: mysql, increment, insert-update

I need to make something like this:

```
INSERT `stats` (`id`,`clicks`) VALUES 
(1, clicks+7),
(2, clicks+3),
....
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `clicks`=VALUES(clicks)
```

in other words, when table has no record with pk `id` - it inserted and `clicks` gets 7 (or 3). When record with PK is present, then old value of `click` should be increased by 7 (or 3). As you can see, increment value for each row is different. Current query always overwrites old value. Please help to modify this query.

Comment: Solution is found by myself: ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `clicks` = `clicks` + VALUES(clicks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `VALUES` have to be literal values, not references to columns:

```
INSERT INTO `stats` (`id`,`clicks`) VALUES 
  (1, 7),
  (2, 3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `clicks`=`clicks` + VALUES(`clicks`)
```